# MySQL: "SELECT text as <HERE A VARIABLE OR SUBQUERY> FROM ......."

Tags: mysql

I have the following Table with the following Data inside:

| id | text | lanuage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | deutscher text | german |
| 2 | english text | english |

What I want is to get the Result in the following Format:

```
german="deutscher text"
english="english text"
```

This menas, it should be **not**:

```
text="deutscher text"
text="english text"
```

The Key/Column Name `text` should be the data from `language`

I tried the following Query but its not working:

```
SELECT text as (SELECT language FROM `table` where id = 1) FROM `table` where id = 1;
```

`(SELECT language FROM` table `where id = 1)` will return "german" so the Query should be:
"SELECT text as german FROM `table` where id = 1;" but this is not working.

Is there a way to do this in one Query?

Cheers, Thomas

Comment: No, it's not possible to calculate labels  in SQL. You'll need to use dynamic SQL in a stored procedure, using `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option you can use is `PREPARED STATEMENT`:

```
SET @sql := NULL;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
           CONCAT('MAX(CASE WHEN language="',language,'" THEN text END) AS "',language,'"')) 
         INTO @sql
FROM mytable;

SELECT CONCAT('SELECT ',@sql,' FROM mytable;') INTO @sql;

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

First step is dynamically assigning columns required to the `@sql` variable. Then, concatenating the previously assigned `@sql` variable with the rest of the final `SELECT` query, then re-assign it to the `@sql` variable. The query will end up with:

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN language="german" THEN text END) AS "german",
       MAX(CASE WHEN language="english" THEN text END) AS "english" 
FROM mytable;
```

Lastly, we prepare, execute then deallocate the statement assigned in the `@sql` variable and you'll get your expected result.

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=81534002f617fc6f8a00e21a46d51152)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to alter your table schema a bit; Added a ref to group the languages to use

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ref` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `text` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `language` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `Index 1` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3;
```

Then the SQL

```sql
SELECT T.text AS english, T2.text AS german
FROM test T 
INNER JOIN test T2 ON T.ref = T2.ref AND T2.`language` = 'german'
WHERE 
    T.ref = 1 AND
    T.language = 'english'
```

The dummy data

```sql
INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `ref`, `text`, `language`) VALUES
    (1, 1, 'deutscher text', 'german'),
    (2, 1, 'english text', 'english');
```

Comment: Hi! The Data can have many different Languages which I dont know. Thats why I want to use it as Varaible and assign it in the select Command : `SELECT T.text AS <HERE THE VARIABLE>"